# Как разобраться с ошибкой _tkinter.TclError: PRIMARY selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу программу на питон, которая работает с формой. Форма состоит из текстовых полей для указания количества выбранных предметов, чекбоксов и выпадающих списков. Суть программы обработать данные из формы и передать их в специальную функцию при нажатии кнопки. Но при нажатии кнопки мне выдаётся ошибка `_tkinter.TclError: PRIMARY selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined`
Можете посоветовать, что делать?

```
def ButtonClick():
    num = 'A' + str(rad_0v) + str(list_0.selection_get()) + entry_0.get()
    art_num = str(check_0_0v) + str(rad_0v) + str(list_0.selection_get()) + str(entry_0.get()) + str(
        combo_list_1.selection_get()) + entry_1.get() + str(combo_list_2.selection_get()) + entry_2.get() + str(
        check_1_3v) + entry_3.get() + str(check_1_4v) + entry_4.get() + str(
        combo_list_5.selection_get()) + entry_5.get() + str(combo_list_6.selection_get()) + entry_6.get() + str(
        combo_list_7.selection_get()) + entry_7.get() + str(combo_list_8.selection_get()) + entry_8.get() + str(
        combo_list_9.selection_get()) + entry_9.get() + str(check_1_10v) + entry_10.get() + str(
        check_1_11v) + entry_11.get() + str(check_1_12v) + entry_12.get() + str(
        combo_list_13.selection_get()) + entry_13.get() + str(combo_list_14.selection_get()) + entry_14.get() + str(
        combo_list_15.selection_get()) + entry_15.get() + str(combo_list_16.selection_get()) + entry_16.get() + str(
        combo_list_17.selection_get()) + entry_17.get() + str(check_1_18v) + entry_18.get() + str(
        check_1_19v) + entry_19.get() + str(combo_list_20.selection_get()) + entry_20.get() + str(
        check_1_21v) + entry_21.get() + str(check_1_22v) + entry_22.get() + str(
        combo_list_23.selection_get()) + entry_23.get() + str(combo_list_24.selection_get()) + entry_24.get() + str(
        combo_list_25.selection_get()) + entry_25.get() + str(combo_list_26.selection_get()) + entry_26.get() + str(
        check_1_27v) + entry_27.get() + str(check_1_28v) + entry_28.get() + str(check_1_29v) + entry_29.get() + str(
        check_1_30v) + entry_30.get() + str(combo_list_31.selection_get()) + entry_31.get()
    print(art_num)
    art_chek(dic, art_dic, num, art_num, 'Combo_history.txt', 'Dictionary_history.txt', label_chat, label_chat_d)
```

Это фрагмент кода, отвечающий за считывания данных из формы.
А это вид формы.

[image]

И полный код ошибки

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Егор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Егор\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\COMBINATOR_PRODUCT\COMBINATOR.py", line 12, in ButtonClick
    num = 'A' + str(rad_0v) + str(list_0.selection_get()) + entry_0.get()
  File "C:\Users\Егор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1007, in selection_get
    return self.tk.call(('selection', 'get') + self._options(kw))
_tkinter.TclError: PRIMARY selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined
```

Вот Код создания различных элементов:

```
combo_list_1 = ttk.Combobox(frame_1, justify=CENTER, state='readonly', values=('нет', '20 см', '40 см', '60 см', '80 см', '100 см', '120 см', '140 см', '160 см', '180 см', '200 см', '220 см', '240 см', '260 см', '280 см', '300 см'))

entry_1 = Entry(frame_1, font='Arial 10', fg='Black', width=3)

check_1_3 = Checkbutton(frame_1, variable=check_1_3v, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font='Arial 10', text='Фильтры бактериальновирусные', fg='Black', bg='White')

list_0 = Listbox(frame_0, font='Arial 11', selectmode=SINGLE, height=3, width=30, selectbackground="purple")
```

Comment: Видимо в list_0 у вас ничего не выбрано. Приведите код создания этого контрола, потому что не понятно что это, и не понятно как вашу ошибку воспроизвести.

Comment: Сейчас добавлю. Буду рад если сможете помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта ошибка просто говорит вам, что ничего не выбрано. Это не ошибка сама по себе , просто это способ сказать: «ничего не получится». Это может быть правдой, или у вас может быть что-то выбранное, но оно не экспортируется в «выбор»

Использование метода `get` с тегами является более правильным, чем использование `selection_get` поскольку в виджетах ничего не может быть выбрано, но у него есть `selection_get` возвращающая что-то (например: возврат любого другого виджета, экспортированного в выборку)

p.s. текст взят из: https://www.rupython.com/tkinter-text_get-110931.html